# Looking for key words in a text file

Tags: c

I want to search for a word in a file by reading only the 1st word of each line and copy the entire line whose 1st word is similar to another file. This code is reading the whole file not 1st word of each line.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int check=1;
    FILE *fp,*fp1;
    char ser[200],oneword[200],c;
    printf("Enter the word:");
    scanf("%s",ser);
    fp=fopen("4HHB.pdb","r");
    fp1=fopen("file2.dat","a+");
    do
    {
     if(check!=0)
     {
         c=fscanf(fp,"%s",oneword);
         //printf("hi  %s\n",oneword);
         check = strcmp(oneword,ser);
     }
     if(check==0)
     {
         //printf("Hello");
         check=1;
         fprintf(fp1,"%s ",oneword);
         c=fgetc(fp);
         while(c!=10&&c!=EOF)   // The ASCII code for \n is 10
         {

            fputc(c,fp1);
            c=fgetc(fp);
           // if(c=="\n")
             //   break;
         }
         fputc(c,fp1);
     }
    }while(c!=EOF);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your problem is? What's wrong with your program? What's your *question*?

Comment: Also, you should really check what [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) actually returns (becase right now `c != EOF` will not work as you expect). And why compare a character with an integer when you can do e.g. `c != '\n'`?

Comment: 1) the returned value from scanf (and family) needs to be checked to assure the input/conversion operations was successful.     2) the length of the string input needs to be inhibited so a buffer overflow (resulting in undefined behaviour and possible seg fault event) does not occur

Comment: OP should read the manual before using a system call.  For instance, fscanf() does NOT return a char.  (It does return a int).   the value 'EOF' is an int, not a char.  fgetc() returns an int, not a char.  therefore, 'c' should be declared an int, not a char

Comment: the returned value from fopen() needs to be checked to assure the operation was successful (!= NULL)

Comment: I want to read only the 1st word of each line and...suppose the 1st word of 1st line and 1st word of 2nd line are same then i want to copy those 2 lines in another file

Answer (score 1):

when a word matches, then the line needs to read/written.

When a word (code is currently checking all words, not just first word of each line) does not match, the rest of the line needs to be read/discarded.

strongly suggest reading each line via fgets(), then parsing the first word to make a decision if the line is to be written or discarded.